# Permissão para abrir a câmera negada no Android SDK 29

Tags: android, react-native

Depois de alterar o SDK para 29, a câmera que costumava abrir normalmente no dia 28 agora tem permissão negada.

Meu projeto é desenvolvido em "react-native": "0.59.9".

Aqui estão algumas informações adicionais:

build.gradle

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

warning:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aponto para quem está lendo que segui as diretrizes deste artigo https://www.reactnativeschool.com/how-to-upgrade-react-native-app-to-api-level-29, no entanto, após o procedimento Estou enfrentando o problema da câmera.

Alguém já enfrentou um problema como este? Eles saberiam como me orientar sobre como proceder?

Comment: Como você está abrindo a câmera? Tem relação com algum pacote?

Comment: estou usando o pacote "react-native-camera": "2.10.1"

Comment: @RafaelTavares, boa tarde! Uma informação importante é que eu testei o código em 2 emuladores diferentes agora há pouco. A camera abriu normalmente no android 9 e no 10 não abriu.

Comment: Pesquisando não encontrei nada sobre permissão de câmera, mas teve uma mudança no privilégio em relação ao sistema de arquivos no Android 10, não sei se é esse o problema porque nunca usei a câmera e não sei se você está tentando acessar um diretório indevido para salvar as fotos, por exemplo

Comment: vc acredita que a versão 0.59 do react native está trazendo algum impacto? Eu estou com dúvidas se devo atualizar a versão ou até mesmo somente a lib da câmera.

Comment: Improvável que esse seja o problema, mas não descarto. Precisaria testar em um projeto limpo na versão atual e na versão 0.59. Mesmo assim, é recomendado manter uma versão mais atualizada, a 0.64 já teve um *release candidate*.

Comment: Perfeito Gabriel. Obrigado pelo apoio! Vou continuar pesquisando por aqui.